# Tree (Linux command): Custom output

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, tree

In a documentation I saw screenshots of the `tree` command output like following:

[image]

In my case I created the filesystem like in the screenshot but in the examples, **there were Files and Subfolders in all of the listed folders** (`Folder1`, `Folder3`, `Folder5` in the example) as well:

Real filesystem structure:

[image]

I know that - in this small scenario - I could use options for `tree` like following:

```
tree -I 'Folder1|Folder3|Folder5'
```

which would exclude those folders, but in a huge Filesystem I could exclude other subfolders with those wildcards, too.

Ergo I need a command where I can set a wildcard for special layers of the trees (`-L` option) and for special subdirectory paths.

The manual to tree didn't help me further (`tree --help` or [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm)).

Is this possible with `tree` or have those screenshots which I mentioned above been faked?

Comment: Which documentation are you following? I can't reproduce your first screenshot either so I'm curious.

Comment: It's not a doc of the tree command but one I am not allowed to publish here. Their is no prompt shown but just the output in the tree-structure and under the screenshot there is a reference to `tree`. It might be that it is impossible and just a manipulated screenshot